# Scala maven builder doesn't understand quasiquotes

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-maven-plugin

I'm building a scala macro project that contains a quasiquote implementation:

```
    val valDefs = named.map { case (child, name) =>
      q"val $name = play.api.libs.json.Json.writes[$child]"
    }
```

However when being compiled, maven builder (using incremental compiling mode) throws this error:

```
[ERROR] /home/peng/git/spookystuff/ispark-macro/src/main/scala/JsMacroImpl.scala:74: value q is not a member of StringContext
[ERROR]           q"val $name = play.api.libs.json.Json.writes[$child]"
[ERROR]           ^
```

I'm very sure my scala is a rather late version: 2.10.4, why it cannot recognize the new standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quasiquotes have been introduced in 2.11](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/changelog211.html). You would need a compiler plugin for 2.10. See [this section](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/changelog211.html#how-to-make-your-2110-macros-work-in-210x) at the same address.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works in sbt, but in maven the compiler also asked me to import a scala experimental feature object before macro declaration. This is the first time I see two build tools requires different codes

Comment: @tribbloid You probably had macros enabled your sbt build file under the `scalacOptions` key. The value is `"-language:experimental.macros"`.